# How to initialize generic enum using a protocol with associated type?

Tags: swift, generics, enums

Consider the following definitions of an enum and a protocol

```swift
enum Result<T> {
    case success(info: T)
    case failure(message: String)
}

protocol Response {
    associatedtype T
    var info: T? { get }
}
```

I am trying to initialize a `Result` using a value that implements `Response` protocol.

The following code does not compile.

```swift
extension Result {
    init(response: Response) {
        // body of the initializer
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
extension Result {
    init<R: Response>(response: R) where R.T == T {
        if let info = response.info {
            self = .success(info: info)
        } else {
            self = .failure(message: "Whoops")
        }
    }
}
```

You can't use protocols-with-associated types directly, so you should use them as generic parameters.